# I need Diarization of speakers, but I don’t know their number in advance

Tags: python

I've been searching for a long time

Does anyone know an solution, preferably with at least some documentation?

pyAudioAnalysis requires you to know the number of speakers in advance. pydiar only works with 2 speakers and looked at many models, where the license needs to be approved, then you need to know in advance how many people